# serving multiple react apps with nodejs and nginx

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, loopbackjs

I have a Loopback App, which provides the API, and serves the static files. And 2 React apps which use the same Loopback App.

I serve the static files (from React Build folders) using serve-static and vhost.

```
  var serveSubdomainAbc = serveStatic('abc/build', {
    index: ['index.html']
  });
  var serveSubdomainXyz = serveStatic('./../../xyz-abc/build', {
    index: ['index.html']
  });

  app.use(vhost('abc.example.com', serveSubdomainAbc));
  app.use(vhost('xyz-abc.example.com', serveSubdomainXyz));
```

I also setup an nginx server with very basic settings.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

When I directly visit the root of the apps, everything works fine, like

- abc.example.com
- xyz-abc.example.com

index.html is served, and then the react app starts fine. When I use a router link like, 
**xyz-abc.example.com/ssoRedirect**, then it cannot find the ssoRedirect and it falls back to abc.example.com's index.html and serves that file, so ssoRedirect does not work. How can I make it to fallback to the correct index.html when it cannot find the required static file.

Comment: I have stopped nginx, and served the app on port 80 directly with nodejs, the behaviour is same, it still fails on prod enviroment for second app, and works fine on my MacBook.

Comment: I ended up with creating a ssoRedirect folder and copying the index.html file in there.

Comment: I also added a middleware to rewrite the req url, this also seems to be working fine.